# MySQL - GROUP BY clause recursively?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Under MySQL I can not group the three separate data columns via GROUP BY clause.

This sample contains four brands, each brand has 2 models and 4 versions of engines. I need to extract 4 vehicles the brand, the model and version of engines is different. A truly **unique result in the 3 columns**.

```
----------+--------+----------+
Brand     | Model  | Version  |
----------+--------+----------+
Renault   | Clio   | Essence  |
Citroen   | C4     | GPL      |
Ford      | Fiesta | Gazole   |
Peugeot   | 206    | Electric |
----------+--------+----------+
```

This works 8/10.

```
SELECT brand, model, version 
    FROM cars WHERE version = (SELECT version FROM cars GROUP BY version ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) 
GROUP BY brand
```

An example of the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

INSERT INTO `cars` (`id`, `brand`, `model`, `version`) VALUES
    (1, 'Renault', 'Clio ', 'Essence'),
    (2, 'Renault', 'Clio ', 'Gazole'),
    (3, 'Renault', 'Clio ', 'GPL'),
    (4, 'Renault', 'Clio ', 'Electric'),
    (5, 'Renault', 'Modus', 'Essence'),
    (6, 'Renault', 'Modus', 'Gazole'),
    (7, 'Renault', 'Modus', 'GPL'),
    (8, 'Renault', 'Modus', 'Electric'),
    (9, 'Peugeot', '307', 'Essence'),
    (10, 'Peugeot', '307', 'Gazole'),
    (11, 'Peugeot', '307', 'GPL'),
    (12, 'Peugeot', '307', 'Electric'),
    (13, 'Peugeot', '206', 'Essence'),
    (14, 'Peugeot', '206', 'Gazole'),
    (15, 'Peugeot', '206', 'GPL'),
    (16, 'Peugeot', '206', 'Electric'),
    (17, 'Citroen', 'C4', 'Essence'),
    (18, 'Citroen', 'C4', 'Gazole'),
    (19, 'Citroen', 'C4', 'GPL'),
    (20, 'Citroen', 'C4', 'Electric'),
    (21, 'Citroen', 'C5', 'Essence'),
    (22, 'Citroen', 'C5', 'Gazole'),
    (23, 'Citroen', 'C5', 'GPL'),
    (24, 'Citroen', 'C5', 'Electric'),
    (25, 'Ford', 'Focus', 'Essence'),
    (26, 'Ford', 'Focus', 'Gazole'),
    (27, 'Ford', 'Focus', 'GPL'),
    (28, 'Ford', 'Focus', 'Electric'),
    (29, 'Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Essence'),
    (30, 'Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Gazole'),
    (31, 'Ford', 'Fiesta', 'GPL'),
    (32, 'Ford', 'Fiesta', 'Electric');
```

Comment: Dude, you say GROUPE BY ????

Comment: The result does not seem to be a group by. Please add more details!!!

Comment: I don't see the connection between your table and the desired result. Can you explain the criteria for determining the result?

Comment: I want to extract a unique data pair (brand, model, version)

Comment: @DavidAman I also don't understand what OP is asking. OP, your desired result is a unique data pair but not unique for the possible values in all columns.

Comment: But why include Ford, Fiesta, Gazole vs., say, Ford, Focus, Gazole. That is unique, too.

Comment: Look closely at the example of desired result above. I want to extract a "unique result". Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I was offered, it is not optimized but it works.

If someone with a suggestion I'm interested.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp AS
SELECT  
    tb1.id AS id1,
    tb1.brand   AS brand1,
    tb1.model   AS model1,
    tb1.version AS version1,
    tb2.id      AS id2,
    tb2.brand   AS brand2,
    tb2.model   AS model2,
    tb2.version AS version2,
    tb3.id      AS id3,
    tb3.brand   AS brand3,
    tb3.model   AS model3,
    tb3.version AS version3,
    tb4.id      AS id4,
    tb4.brand   AS brand4,
    tb4.model   AS model4,
    tb4.version AS version4
FROM `cars` AS tb1
    INNER JOIN `cars` AS tb2
        ON  tb2.brand   != tb1.brand
        AND tb2.model   != tb1.model
        AND tb2.version != tb1.version
        AND tb2.id      >  tb1.id
    INNER JOIN `cars` AS tb3
        ON  tb3.brand   != tb2.brand
        AND tb3.model   != tb2.model
        AND tb3.version != tb2.version
        AND tb3.id      >  tb2.id
        AND tb3.brand   != tb1.brand
        AND tb3.model   != tb1.model
        AND tb3.version != tb1.version
        AND tb3.id      >  tb1.id
    INNER JOIN `cars` AS tb4
        ON  tb4.brand   != tb3.brand
        AND tb4.model   != tb3.model
        AND tb4.version != tb3.version
        AND tb4.id      >  tb3.id
        AND tb4.brand   != tb2.brand
        AND tb4.model   != tb2.model
        AND tb4.version != tb2.version
        AND tb4.id      >  tb2.id
        AND tb4.brand   != tb1.brand
        AND tb4.model   != tb1.model
        AND tb4.version != tb1.version
        AND tb4.id      >  tb1.id
LIMIT 1

--------------
select * from sample
--------------

+-----+---------+--------+----------+-----+---------+--------+----------+-----+---------+--------+----------+-----+--------+--------+----------+
| id1 | brand1  | model1 | version1 | id2 | brand2  | model2 | version2 | id3 | brand3  | model3 | version3 | id4 | brand4 | model4 | version4 |
+-----+---------+--------+----------+-----+---------+--------+----------+-----+---------+--------+----------+-----+--------+--------+----------+
|   1 | Renault | Clio   | Essence  |  10 | Peugeot | 307    | Gazole   |  19 | Citroen | C4     | GPL      |  28 | Ford   | Focus  | Electric |
+-----+---------+--------+----------+-----+---------+--------+----------+-----+---------+--------+----------+-----+--------+--------+----------+
```

and get the result formatter

```
SELECT  id1 AS id,
        brand1   AS brand,
        model1   AS model,
        version1 AS version
FROM temp

UNION

SELECT  id2      AS id,
        brand2   AS brand,
        model2   AS model,
        version2 AS version
FROM temp

UNION

SELECT  id3      AS id,
        brand3   AS brand,
        model3   AS model,
        version3 AS version
FROM temp

UNION

SELECT  id4      AS id,
        brand4   AS brand,
        model4   AS model,
        version4 AS version
FROM temp

+----+---------+-------+----------+
| id | brand   | model | version  |
+----+---------+-------+----------+
|  1 | Renault | Clio  | Essence  |
| 10 | Peugeot | 307   | Gazole   |
| 19 | Citroen | C4    | GPL      |
| 28 | Ford    | Focus | Electric |
+----+---------+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique/distinct set of (Brand,Model,Version) add all three column name in `GROUP BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT brand, model, version FROM cars 
WHERE version = (SELECT version FROM cars GROUP BY version ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) 
GROUP BY brand, model, version
```

Comment: I get duplicate results on the 3 columns

Comment: Did you try your code? I get duplicate results on the 3 columns

Comment: Here is the result:
`(Citroen,C4,Electric)
(Ford,Focus,Electric)
(Peugeot,307,GPL)
(Renault,Clio ,Gazole)
(Renault,Clio ,GPL)
(Renault,Modus,Electric)
(Renault,Modus,Essence)`

Comment: the result you paste,  there is no duplicate row with same (brand,model,version) e.g. ``A1,B2,C3`` and ``A1,B2,C1`` are totally unique. Where is your duplicate?

Comment: I want a **totally** unique result `(Citroen,C4,Electric) 
(Peugeot,307,GPL) 
(Renault,Clio,Gazole) `

Comment: Then tell me how you are picking ``'Renault', 'Clio ', 'Essence'`` not ``'Renault', 'Clio ', 'Gazole')``. What is the logic?

Comment: This works 8/10 `SELECT brand, model, version FROM cars WHERE version = (SELECT version FROM cars GROUP BY version ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) GROUP BY brand` Test this code to understand the desired result, I can not be clearer than that.

Comment: I'm full confused! ``8/10`` meaning?

Comment: You are saying 80% time its working ? then its not a correct solution.